# Values doesnt save into mysql database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Im trying to save values into a database however when trying to input the data it doesnt appear in the table and the except output is shown.

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
host = 'localhost',
user = 'root',
passwd = 'pswrd'
)
mycursor = connection.cursor()

mycursor.execute('USE test')

def save_results():  
   print('Please enter your first and last name...')  
   name = (input('Enter: '))  

   try:
       mycursor.execute('USE test')
       mycursor.execute("SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE (name) = ('" + name +"');")
       mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('" + name + "');")
       connection.commit()
       print('s')
   except:
       print('ASDASD')
```

I want the input to appear in the table.

Comment: **WARNING**: This code has some severe vulnerable to [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you don't [properly prepare your statement](http://bobby-tables.com/python). Never use string interpolation with `%` or `{...}` or concatenation, instead use placeholders (`%s`) and pass through the arguments as a separate tuple to the `execute` function.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `SELECT` query? You never fetch the results.

Answer (score 0):

this might sound totally stupid but, have you checked the password is correct?

Comment: yes the password is correct the and im pretty sure the database in connected

Answer (score 0):

You omit to define the database name when making an object of connect:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)
```